# How do I combine static values with csv source data in Azure Data Factory

Tags: salesforce, azure-data-factory, jitterbit

Up until recently, I've been using Jitterbit to upsert data into Salesforce. I generate an external ID through the upsert by mapping a column from the CSV source called *license_no* to a field in Salesforce called *License_External_ID__c*. From there I'm able to easily append whatever static strings I want to the source value. I'm not sure how to make this happen in ADF.

[Jitterbit Concatenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbdHG.png)

Attached are screenshots of what I have set up in ADF so far and the equivalent mapping in Jitterbit. To avoid confusion, I'll note that *license_no* is also being directly mapped to a field in SF called *License_Number__c*, but again, I want to take the same value and transform it into an external ID. In other words, taking a license number that equals *123456* and transforming it into *Dentist_MD_123456* as shown in the first screenshot.

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkJy8.png)

[Sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANlGX.png)

[Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMALT.png)

[Jitterbit Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRNMV.png)

Answer (score 0):

- To manipulate data in azure data factory, you can use dataflows. The following is the demonstration about the same.
- Let's say I have the following data in my source csv:

[image]

- Now to add a new column (or change value of an existing column), you can use derived column transformation. I have a parameter called `license_no` (static value) and created a new column as shown below using the expression `concat('Dentist_MD_',$license_no)`.

[image]

- The result would be as shown in the below image:

[image]

- For any data manipulation activities, you can use the transformations provided by azure dataflows. You can configure your mapping in the sink section same as in copy data activity.